# Creating Dynamic XPath with function parameters (WebdriverIO)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ui-automation, webdriver-io, wdio

So I  am automating testing of a command centre style of web application (essentially fool-proofed SQL statements with tonnes of field validation on the front end).
There are 125 of these statements under 20 categories which when clicked expand/collapse to show/hide its child commands.
Rather than specify 125 getter functions (and a 125-case switch on the parameter passed by cucumber) is there a way to dynamically create XPath selectors using the parameter passed by cucumber? For example:

```
When(/^I select (.*) menu item$/, async (menuItem) => {
    switch (menuItem) {
        case "Activate User":
            await PageObject.element1.click();
            break;
        case "Change Email Address":
            await PageObject.element2.click();
            break;
        case "Change User Password":
            await PageObject.element3.click();
            break;
           //ETC 122 more times
```

It would be so much easier to have a single line find and click the [li] element like:

```
When(/^I select (.*) menu item$/, async (menuItem) => {
            await browser.$('//li[contains(text(),\'' + menuItem + '\')]').click();
}
```

But this doesn't work. Anybody have any idea why or have any suggestions on how to get it to work? Thanks, Shep

Answer (score 0):

```
When(/^I select \"([^\"]*)\" menu item$/,  async function (menuItem) {
    const menu_item = await $('//li[contains(text(),\'' + menuItem+ '\')]')
    console.log(menu_item )
    await menu_item.click()
});
```

worked on my code. i hope this can solve your problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).